# node orm hasone relationship

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

I'm trying to use a simple hasOne relationship with node orm module:

```
var Shop = db.define('shops', {
    id: { type: "serial", key: true },
    name: String
});

var Offer = db.define('offers', {
    id: { type: "serial", key: true },
    name: String
});
Offer.hasOne('shop', Shop);
```

Then i would like to get the shop of a selected offer; in the doc it is written that the hasOne relationship sets up a new method, getShop in this case:

```
Offer.find(1, function (err, firstOffer) {
    if (err) throw err;

    firstOffer.getShop(function(err, shop) {
        res.send(shop);
    });        
});
```

but everything crashes saying that firstOffer has no method 'getShop'...
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing find with get.
Please change your code to (note the get in the first line):

```
Offer.get(1, function (err, firstOffer) {
  if (err) throw err;
  firstOffer.getShop(function(err, shop) {
    res.send(shop);
  });        
});
```

When you do a find then it returns an array (it can return an empty array), so you are calling the getShop for the array.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but after a few I decided to use Sequelize that suits me better...